# Why isn't my div float:right working?

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to understand why my div won't float:right. I want it to appear on the right side of the page to where it mirrors the left side. Also, is there a way to center a div on the y-axis (top-bottom)? If so, how?

All of my code is below or here is a CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNKBJr

HTML:

```
<div id="page">
<div class="mobile-hidden" style="float:left;position:absolute;">
</div>
<div class="mobile-hidden" style="float:right;position:absolute;">
</div>
<center>
<div class="content">
<div style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 72pt;">
  <p>Page Content Here</p>
</div>
    <center>
  <div style="margin-top:23px;">
  </div>
</center></div></center>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top:170px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    z-index:10;
    width:660px;
}

.mobile-hidden {
    display:none;
}

#page {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;    
}

@media screen and (min-width:1260px){
    .mobile-hidden {
    display:block;
    width:300px;
    height:100%;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    z-index:20;
    /**/
    background-color:#DCDCDC;
    /**/
    }
}
```

Comment: Mind you that`<div class="mobile-hidden">` is hidden on screens smaller than 1260px, or at least it should be that way so you may need to adjust that number in the CSS if your screen is too small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about removing the inline `position:absolute;`?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myKRdO

By the way the mobile menu, is it meant to be `max-width:1260px`?

Comment: That did it! Thanks! I have no idea why I had that in the first place. Regarding the mobile, I am using `min-width:1260px` because of what I plan to do with the page where `max-width:1260px` is more of a hassle to work with. Know of any ways to center a div vertically?